# What latch would work best for a front/top opening chest?

Tags: furniture, hardware

I'm building a chest (about 3' wide, 2' deep, 2' tall) where the front folds up over the top (270 degrees), then the front/top fold again to the back (another 270 degrees).  I need to know how best to latch it closed.

I'd like the latch to be spring loaded.  It does not need to lock.  I would like it to latch itself when the chest is closed, rather than needing to pull the spring back then move the front into place.

I was thinking of something along the lines of a [laptop lid](http://cdn3.iofferphoto.com/img/item/183/322/659/7mTn.jpg), where there's a hook that latches itself when closed, and a lever to slide the hook out of the way so it can open.  The catch plate would be on the bottom, and it would latch when the top/front is put down (rather than the front being swung into place alone).  I wasn't able to find anything like it online, probably because I have no idea what it's called.

The other idea I had would be to use something like a door latch on both bottom corners, which would latch when the front is swung into place.  Instead of a knob, you would slide the latch open.  [Like this](http://www.alibaba.com/product-gs/256747879/stainless_steel_spring_door_lock_latch/showimage.html) but furniture quality.

I really do not want something industrial/utility looking [like this](http://rbhinge.com/products.asp?lbid=53).

Can you help me locate something like what I'm looking for (or something better I haven't thought of)?

(I don't know much about hardware terminology, so please forgive me...)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want something like a tambour door lock like this:

[image: Tambour Door Lock]

You can find it [here](http://www.rockler.com/product.cfm?page=668).

Comment: that's very close. do they make something similar that slides instead of turns? and/or without a key?

Comment: Tried, but couldn't quickly find anything without a lock.  You'd think someone would make one with a knob instead of a lock.  You could try a [window sash lock](http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1v/R-202890861/h_d2/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053).  A little bulky, but that might work.

Answer (score 0):

How strong does the catch need to be? Would [Rare Earth Magnets](http://www.axminster.co.uk/axminster-rare-earth-magnets-prod19790) suffice? You could counter sink them into the wood and super glue or Epoxy them in place. I would recommend a very strong glue because these magnets are ridiculously powerful.

Comment: Thanks for your response Bernhard.  It really has to be a physical latch, I'd be afraid it would open if it were being moved and the contents shifted.